# TLS initialization failed on GET Request

Tags: c++, json, qt

I'm starting with qt/c++ and on my project I need to make a json post/get/put but  I'm trying to do a simple get request but I have an error: `qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed`

I don't know why, I tried some methods but all put the same message. I attach the code that I use.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::replyFini(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << "answer------------>"<<answer;
}

void MainWindow::on_btn_login_clicked()
{
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://httpbin.org/get"));
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFini(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(request);
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SSL libraries are not found. The error can be read out in the [Qt Src](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs-1/blob/master/src/qt/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp#L426). Either deploy them with your application or install OpenSSL on your machine.

Also, just a small hint:

```
void MainWindow::replyFini(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << "answer------------>"<<answer;
}
```

You should call `reply->deleteLater();`

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_login_clicked()
{
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://httpbin.org/get"));
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFini(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(request);
}
```

Add `connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::deleteLater);`to avoid a memory leak on each click.

Comment: Thank you so much!. I installed this **Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2q Light** from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and just add to my .pro file the line:
          INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include

Comment: If you do install OpenSSL on your machine, you'll be given the choice of copying the ssl libraries to the bin directory of the install folder, or to the windows system32 directory. It worked for me by copying to the bin dir, and then putting that dir on my system path - I didn't need to make any changes to the .pro file. That way it should work for the next project you create/open that uses HTTPS too.

Answer (score 38):

On Windows if you install Qt via online installer, you can select OpenSSL Toolkit as an optional component. This should provide you with the version definitely compatible with your Qt.

If you haven't checked it during installation, you can rerun `C:\Qt\MaintenanceTool.exe` and select Add or remove components. OpenSSL Toolkit is located under the Developer and Designer Tools section, it is the last entry.

However, there's a note in the sidebar:

> Qt installer doesn't set up OpenSSL environment. User needs to define the path and environment variables.

So once installed, you should add the directory with the DLLs to the PATH environment variable or place the needed DLLs near the `.exe` file (copy them to the `debug` and `release` directories of your project).

The directory is located at `C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\bin` (or `Win_x86` if you need 32-bit version). The DLLs are named `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` and `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` in my case.

---

But this wasn't enough to deploy it to another machine, after copying it all I got the same error again. The reason came out to be that OpenSSL DLLs depend on another MSVC runtime version than the Qt app itself, and these errors go unreported. Open these DLLs in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what's missing. In my case it was `MSVCR100.dll`, so I had to install [MSVC 2010 Redistributable x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523) ([x86 is here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)).

Comment: When you add it to PATH you must to restart Qt Creator. This command opens the environment window from command line on Windows: `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since this is the correct way to do this on windows.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to download from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html the OpenSSL light version (for my compiler) and copy the libcrypto and libssl DLLs from c:\Program Files\OpenSSL\ to my program's .exe folder.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue while trying to integrate the arcGIS geographic mapping system into Qt Creator and was only able to resolve it after I learned that different releases of Qt require different releases of openSSL. I was working with Qt Creator 5.15.2 and was encountering the error because I had installed the newest version of openSSL. Using this line of code

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::supportsSsl() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

I was able to identify the version of openSSL Qt was looking for (don't forget `#include <QSslSocket>` for this to work). Once I installed the correct version (1.1.1q) everything worked perfectly.

[Here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) is a link to download different releases of openSSL. It is also still necessary to add the needed built-in wrapper using the qt maintenance tool -> developer tools -> openSSL.

Finally a good way to check which, if any, version of openSSL is currently on your computer (at least with windows) is by simply typing this command into command prompt.

```
$ openSSL version
```

This should result in either the current version of openSSL your OS is running, or will inform you that the command isn't recognized.