# QNetworkAccessManager does not work on windows with https

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, download, qt5

I'm trying to download files from a `https` url with my application using the following code in `Qt5`. This works perfectly as I want on Linux but with the Windows version `content` is always empty and consequently the exception is thrown.

According to comments and research it seems to be related to `SSL`

```cpp
void FileDownloader::download(QString url, QString dest)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();
    QByteArray content = response->readAll();

    if (content.isEmpty())
        throw std::logic_error((QString("Impossible to download url : ") + url).toStdString());

    QSaveFile file(dest);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(content);
    file.commit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried performing an http request first? Is [`QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#sslErrors) emitted? Does Qt print some error messages in debug mode?

Comment: I confirm it does no throw exception with `http` request but I don't know how to catch a `QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors` so I can't anwser yet.

Comment: Using [signal and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html): `connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(yourslot(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)));`. `yourslot` should be a slot defined in `FileDownloader`. Using a lambda as slot works too.

Comment: I did no succeed in running this but I think I found my answer. I must enable openssl in Qt for windows. Other answers with openssl keyword seems to point in that direction.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please consider creating an answer yourself and/or link the other question that solved your problem. This may be useful for others with the same problem.

Comment: I definitively did not solve it. The problem is worst than expected. I'm searching how to work with openssl. But at least now I know it is not a problem with the code I wrote

Comment: I thing finding a storage location that is not https will be simpler than setting up openssl on windows

Answer (score 1):

It took me literally an entire day to figure out how to make it working. I eventually found the answer [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/128503/how-to-install-openssl-toolkit-using-qt-maintenancetool-on-windows-10).

1. In Qt maintenance tool select **Qt > Developer and Designer Tools > OpenSSL 1.1.x Toolkit** and install it
2. Add the following in `.pro`

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/Tools/OpenSSL/Win_x86/include
   LIBS += -LC:/Qt/Tools/OpenSSL/Win_x86/bin -llibcrypto-1_1 -llibssl-1_1
   ```
3. Copy `libcrypto-1_1.dll` and `libssl-1_1.dll` from `C:/Qt/Tools/OpenSSL/Win_x86/bin` with your program

What took me the whole day was to find step 1.

Comment: This saved me an entire day of debugging! The Qt docs about SSL talks about "building Qt from source". But it didn't mention what you needed to configure the app you build with Qt to make HTTPS (SSL) work.

Comment: For me it was enough to just copy the DLLs, without changing the project. (I don't include any headers from OpenSSL, just want "https" URLs to work.) There is the question of which version of DLLs to copy. This is not straightforward, but is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027595/1889018